# String split with spaces using regex

Tags: regex, split, apache-nifi

I am trying to split a string using regex. I need to use regex in **nifi** to split a string into groups. Could anyone helps me how to split below string using regex.

or how can we give specific occurrence number of delimiter to split the string. For example in the below string how can I specify that I want a string after 3rd occurrence of space.

Suppose i have a String

```
"6/19/2017 12:14:07 PM 0FA0 PACKET 0000000DF5EC3D80 UDP Snd 11.222.333.44 93c8 R Q [8085 A DR NOERROR] PTR (2)73(3)191(3)250(2)10(7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)"
```

And I want result something like this :

```
group 1 - 6/19/2017 12:14:07 PM
group 2 - 0FA0
group 3 - PACKET 0000000DF5EC3D80
group 4 - UDP
group 5 - Snd
group 6 - 11.222.333.44
group 7 - 93c8
group 8 - R Q [8085 A DR NOERROR] PTR (2)73(3)191(3)250(2)10(7)in-
          addr(4)arpa(0)
```

Could anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you searching for somethink [like this](https://regex101.com/r/qFE95M/3)?

Comment: I did something like that if the format of the data are not fixed and only the spaces are the thing to trust : https://regex101.com/r/OikYiX/1 And use only the groups needed. If the date ending by `AM` or `PM` are fixed, the number of char in (`UDP`, `Snd`, etc) also, etc. You can be more specific in the regex like @horcrux did.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your reply. First expression suggested by Horcrux is working great. Second expression suggested by Esteban is working good for given string but if there would be any length change in any group then it breaks.
Yes, format is not fixed so we can trust only at space delimiter.
Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really just certain spaces you want to have for delimiters you can do something like this to avoid a fixed width nightmare:

```
regex = "(\S+\s\S+\s\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+\s\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(.*)"
```

Pretty much it's what it looks like, groups of NON spaces \S+ with spaces \s and each is grouped with parans.  The .* at the end is just the rest of the line, it can be adjusted as needed.  If you wanted each group to be every non spaced group you can do a split instead of regex, but it looks like that isn't what is desired.  I don't have access to nifi to test, but here is an example in Python.

```
import re

text = "6/19/2017 12:14:07 PM 0FA0 PACKET 0000000DF5EC3D80 UDP Snd 11.222.333.44 93c8 R Q [8085 A DR NOERROR] PTR (2)73(3)191(3)250(2)10(7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)"
regex = "(\S+\s\S+\s\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+\s\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(.*)"

match = re.search(regex, text)
print ("group 1 - " + match.group(1))
print ("group 2 - " + match.group(2))
print ("group 3 - " + match.group(3))
print ("group 4 - " + match.group(4))
print ("group 5 - " + match.group(5))
print ("group 6 - " + match.group(6))
print ("group 7 - " + match.group(7))
print ("group 8 - " + match.group(8))
```

Output:

```
group 1 - 6/19/2017 12:14:07 PM
group 2 - 0FA0
group 3 - PACKET 0000000DF5EC3D80
group 4 - UDP
group 5 - Snd
group 6 - 11.222.333.44
group 7 - 93c8
group 8 - R Q [8085 A DR NOERROR] PTR (2)73(3)191(3)250(2)10(7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This expression is working good. Appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to extract every group into a separate attribute? This is certainly possible in "pure" NiFi, but with lines this long, it may make more sense to use [`ExecuteScript`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html) processor to use Groovy or Python's more complex regular expression handling in conjunction with `String#split()` and provide a script like *sniperd* posted.

---

To perform this task using `ExtractText`, you'll configure it as follows:

[image: ExtractText processor configuration]

Copyable patterns:

```
group 1: (^\S+\s\S+\s\S+)
group 2: (?i)(?<=\s)([a-f0-9]{4})(?=\s)
group 3: (?i)(?<=\s)(PACKET\s[a-f0-9]{4,16})(?=\s)
group 4: (?i)(?<=\s\S{16}\s)([\w]{3,})(?=\s)
group 5: (?i)(?<=\s.{3}\s)([\w]{3,})(?=\s)
group 6: (?i)(?<=\s.{3}\s)([\d\.]{7,15})(?=\s)
group 7: (?i)(?<=\d\s)([a-f0-9]{4})(?=\s)
group 8: (?i)(?<=\d\s[a-f0-9]{4}\s)(.*)$
```

It is important to note that `Include Capture Group 0` is set to `false`. You will get duplicate groups (`group 1` and `group 1.1`) due to the way regex expressions are validated in NiFi (currently all regexes **must have at least one capture group** -- this will be fixed with [NIFI-4095 | ExtractText should not require a capture group in every regular expression](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4095)).

The resulting flowfile has the attributes properly populated:[image: Populated flowfile attributes]

Full log output:

```
2017-06-20 14:45:57,050 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-9] o.a.n.processors.standard.LogAttribute LogAttribute[id=c6b04310-015c-1000-b21e-c64aec5b035e] logging for flow file StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=5209cc65-08fe-44a4-be96-9f9f58ed2490,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1497984255809-1, container=default, section=1], offset=444, length=148],offset=0,name=1920315756631364,size=148]
--------------------------------------------------
Standard FlowFile Attributes
Key: 'entryDate'
    Value: 'Tue Jun 20 14:45:10 EDT 2017'
Key: 'lineageStartDate'
    Value: 'Tue Jun 20 14:45:10 EDT 2017'
Key: 'fileSize'
    Value: '148'
FlowFile Attribute Map Content
Key: 'filename'
    Value: '1920315756631364'
Key: 'group 1'
    Value: '6/19/2017 12:14:07 PM'
Key: 'group 1.1'
    Value: '6/19/2017 12:14:07 PM'
Key: 'group 2'
    Value: '0FA0'
Key: 'group 2.1'
    Value: '0FA0'
Key: 'group 3'
    Value: 'PACKET 0000000DF5EC3D80'
Key: 'group 3.1'
    Value: 'PACKET 0000000DF5EC3D80'
Key: 'group 4'
    Value: 'UDP'
Key: 'group 4.1'
    Value: 'UDP'
Key: 'group 5'
    Value: 'Snd'
Key: 'group 5.1'
    Value: 'Snd'
Key: 'group 6'
    Value: '11.222.333.44'
Key: 'group 6.1'
    Value: '11.222.333.44'
Key: 'group 7'
    Value: '93c8'
Key: 'group 7.1'
    Value: '93c8'
Key: 'group 8'
    Value: 'R Q [8085 A DR NOERROR] PTR (2)73(3)191(3)250(2)10(7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)'
Key: 'group 8.1'
    Value: 'R Q [8085 A DR NOERROR] PTR (2)73(3)191(3)250(2)10(7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)'
Key: 'path'
    Value: './'
Key: 'uuid'
    Value: '5209cc65-08fe-44a4-be96-9f9f58ed2490'
--------------------------------------------------
6/19/2017 12:14:07 PM 0FA0 PACKET 0000000DF5EC3D80 UDP Snd 11.222.333.44 93c8 R Q [8085 A DR NOERROR] PTR (2)73(3)191(3)250(2)10(7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
```

---

Another option with the release of NiFi 1.3.0 is to use the [record processing capabilities](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html). This is a new feature which allows arbitrary input formats (Avro, JSON, CSV, etc.) to be parsed and manipulated in a streaming manner. Mark Payne has written a [very good tutorial here](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/record-oriented-data-with-nifi) that introduces the feature and provides some simple walkthroughs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This expression is working fine. I have seen that in each line of expression you fixed the length but the length might not be the same for another record. There would be only delimiter is space. I don't know what length will be for each group. It can vary. Could you please let me know the expression which can make output group based on spaces.

Comment: That's going to be very difficult. You will have more success using `ExecuteScript` and `split()` and then reconstituting elements into the desired strings.

Comment: You can also use the record parsing capabilities -- Bryan Bende just [published an example using Grok -> JSON](http://bryanbende.com/development/2017/06/20/apache-nifi-records-and-schema-registries) that is a perfect match for your problem.

Comment: Those features are in version 1.2.0 or 1.3.0 but I am using version 1.1.0. Now I will move to 1.3.0 and will try to resolve this issue. Thanks Andy for your help.